# NullPointerException in ParseFacebookUtils.logInInBackground

Tags: java, android, facebook, parse-platform

I'm trying to use facebook login with parse instead of facebook sdk login. Because it seems easier to me.
Here is my code:

```
    Button facebookLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);
    facebookLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final ProgressDialog progressBar = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            progressBar.setCancelable(false);
            progressBar.setMessage("Loading ...");
            progressBar.show();
            ParseFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                    if (parseUser == null) {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                    } else if (parseUser.isNew()) {
                        // First launch of the application
                        startApplication(true);
                    } else {
                        // Not the first launch of application
                        startApplication(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

And this code causes a NullPointerExceptoin. Here is the log:

```
9190-9190/ergotech.com.cricket E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ergotech.com.cricket, PID: 9190
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.facebook.AccessToken.getUserId()' on a null object reference
            at com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.getAuthData(FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java:200)
            at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(ParseFacebookUtils.java:135)
            at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(ParseFacebookUtils.java:149)
            at ergotech.com.cricket.Activity.LoginActivity$5.onClick(LoginActivity.java:190)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4832)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19839)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

This is the code from Application class, where I initialize Parse and Facebook, I changed my real IDs on "MyParseID:

```
Parse.initialize(this, "MyParseID", "MyParseID");

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(getApplicationContext());
```

And this is code from the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

I have shown this code, because I think I made all what guide required, but login is not working.
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
After changing `ParseFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new LogInCallback()` on `ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("user_status", "public_profile", "email", "user_likes"), new LogInCallback()` there is no NPE anymore. But now I log in with anonymous user instead of facebook user.

Comment: Because you provide AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() which is null when user is not login. That cause NPE.

Comment: You're right, I started using method logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground which is not requiring AccessToken and there is no NPE. But it logs in with anonymous user.

Comment: What versions of the SDKs are you using?

Comment: @BjörnKaiser Now I use Facebook SDK 4.1.2, Parse 1.9.2 and ParseFacebookUtils 1.9.2